# Are the following premises and conclusions begging the question?

Tags: logic

**Argument 1**

**P1** Everything that is **not X** is **Y**

**P2** Given that **Z** is **not X**

**C** Therefore **Z** is **Y**

**Argument 2**

**P1** Everything that is **X** is **not Y**

**P2** Given that **Z** is **X**

**C** Therefore **Z** is **not Y**

To be clear 'is' between emboldened terms stands for 'is a subset of' or ⊆.

If I say: "Everything that is not a fruit (**not-X**) is edible (**Y**). Everything that is a fruit (**X**) is not edible (**not-Y**). Bob (**Z**) is not a fruit (**not-X**). Therefore Bob (**Z**) is edible (**Y**)".

Does this make sense?

Similarly, if I say "Everything that is not a fruit (**not-X**) is edible (**Y**). Everything that is a fruit (**X**) is not edible (**not-Y**). This tomato (**Z**) is a fruit (**X**). Therefore this tomato (**Z**) is not edible (**not-Y**)".

Does this also make sense?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75734/discussion-on-question-by-questioningthis-are-the-following-premises-and-conclus). (questioningthis: I hope you can see and participate in that room. Normally, one needs more reputation for that but it should work in this case. If not, please @ me and we'll find a solution. -- Also, welcome to Philosophy.SE!)

Answer (score 1):

The question is still ambiguous: "is" can refer either to individuals belonging to a set or to a subset included into a set.

Consider the example with Bob; we have:

P1) Everything not X is Y --- we read it as set inclusion : **not-X ⊆ Y** [where **⊆** is the [subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) relation]

P2) Bob is not X --- **B ∈ not-X** [where **∈** is the [elementhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)#Notation_and_terminology) relation]

C) Bob is Y --- **B ∈ Y**.

The deduction is correct, because the definition of *subset* is : **A ⊆ M** iff every element of **A** is an element of **M**.

Thus, Bob is an element of set **not-X** and **not-X** is subset of **Y**; therefore, Bob is element of **Y**.

> "Everything that is not a fruit (**not-X**) is edible (**Y**). Bob is not a fruit (**X**). Therefore Bob is edible (**Y**)".

---

Similarly for :

> "Everything that is a fruit (**X**) is inedible (**not-Y**). Tomatos (**Z**) are fruits (**X**). Therefore tomatos (**Z**) are not edible (**not-Y**)".

We have :

P1) Everything that is X is not Y --- **X ⊆ not-Y**

P2) Everything that is Z is X --- **Z ⊆ X**

C) Z is not Y --- **Z ⊆ not-Y**.

Also this deduction is correct, because the relation of *inclusion* ("being a subset of") is transitive.

Comment: The question was edited while you were answering.

Comment: @MichaelK - nothing changes.

Comment: Does this mean I would need to clarify whether 'is' defines a set or a subset belonging to a set to be more precise? Furthermore, is this impossible to do?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Eh, yes it does because P3 was added.

Comment: @questioningthis - I've used the standard math symbols: **∈** for element-set and **⊆** for subset-set.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have now edited the original premises to include the symbols for subset. If this is considered to be precise, would it be begging the question?

Comment: I have to question the validity here.  Is the following argument of the same form: Some animals are not mammals. All digs are animals. Therefore some dogs are not mammals.  If the middle terms are in identical spots the argument is NOT valid.  You say it is valid because you know the truth of the premises only and the conclusion is also true. The form is invalid.  The all quantified was used and the some are not quantifier was used. Unless I have the quantifier wrong in the premises the argument is a fallacy of undistributed middle.

Answer (score 0):

> Are the following premises and conclusions begging the question?

Both arguments are valid. Assuming the truth of the premises, I do not see a problem with the reasoning itself. Both arguments are in the Form AAA in the first figure, which is valid.

I do not see any question-begging.

> To **beg the question** is to assume the truth of the conclusion of an
>   argument in the premises in order for the conclusion to follow. It is
>   a type of circular reasoning and an informal fallacy, in which an
>   arguer makes an argument that requires the desired conclusion to be
>   true.  (Wikipedia, “Begging the question”.)

Barker demands more rigor when defining "to beg the question":

> A speaker can prove a conclusion only if his argument contains
>   premises…. (2) that are such that the speaker and his hearers can know
>   them to be true without being aware of whether the conclusion is
>   true….
>
> If the premises are related to the conclusion in such an intimate way
>   that the speaker and his hearers could not have less reason to doubt
>   the premises than they have to doubt the conclusion, then the argument
>   is worthless as a proof…. (Barker, The Elements of Logic (1965), pp
>   175-76.)

Here is how I interpret Barker. The argument begs the question when the premises are related to the conclusion in this way: The following becomes impossible: There is less reason to doubt the premises than there is to doubt the conclusion.

Thus, when there is less reason to doubt the premises than there is to doubt the conclusion, then the argument is valid. Otherwise, the listener must assume some part of the conclusion to balance the lingering doubts about the premises.